# AmpScript Custom Functions

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have been using AMPscript for a while and I know that there is no way to create custom functions. I was wondering if anybody has come up with an alternative for this?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal is re-using code, then Content Areas are the closest thing to simulating a function.

If you create a Content Area (function) that accepts certain variables (interface), you can have the Content Area output a value or whatever.  E.g.:

In your email:

```
%%[ 

/* Interface */
set @number1 = 1 
set @number2 = 2

]%%
<!-- call the function --> 
%%=TreatAsContent(ContentAreaByName("My Contents\AddFunction"))=%%

<!-- output the result of the function -->
<br>The sum is %%=v(@sum)=%%
```

In the `AddFunction` Content Area:

```
%%[

 /* function */
 set @sum = add(@number1,@number2)

]%%
```

**Output**

```
The sum is 3
```

I have a more specific example on [my blog](http://sprignaturemoves.com/ca-xml/) that deals with displaying products in an email.

Comment: So basically the TreatAsContent method renders AMPscript, that's why @sum can return the value. Very smart, thank you so much!

Comment: Clever. Thank you. This will tidy up my massive and unreadable AMP snippets quite a bit.